# Find users of a specific page with visit time in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, visitors

I need to find users of a specific page with visit time in google analytics.

like this report

```
 example.com/example
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think Google Analytics would provide that information.   Google Analytics only provides roll-up summary information as far as I know.  It doesn't provide information about each hit or each visitor.

Comment: Stephen is correct, for privacy reasons individual user data is very difficult to get at in Google Analytics. You'd have to manually extract it with the User Explorer as Vibhor suggests. However, time on page is a pretty unreliable number in GA anyway - if the visitor loads the page but performs no additional action tracked by GA, their time on page will be recorded as 0 even if they spent an hour reading and rereading it.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the Users in `Audiance > User Explorer` section:

[image]

In that section, you will get the user information and on click of that individual user you can get all the pages he visited. And that user data is exportable in JSON format so you can run your query by exporting that data.

Comment: @ I want page users, not users :)

Comment: There no individual page user record section in the Google Analytics dashboard. And the users count that listed for every page are just collective user count and not the data or record of individual users. So your best bet would be from the `User Explorer` section only. :)